# Laravel - Carbon unexpected data

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have started a little projecet with Laravel.
Everthing work fine, just not with Firefox.
I got always the error message, that carbon get unexcepetet data.
But in all other browsers it works.

I tried to change the input field "data" for deadline_date
in to "text" and get the message again. if i deactivate the passages for "deadline_date" everthing work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqNbW.jpg

Controller

```
public function create(StoreMilestone $request)
{
    Milestone::create([
        'name'          => $request->input('name'),
        'deadline_date' => $request->input('deadline'),
        'description'   => $request->input('description')
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Validation

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'        => 'required',
        'deadline'    => 'required|date',
        'description' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Milestone extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

public $timestamps  = false;
protected $table    = 'fairkatert_milestone';
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'deadline_date', 'description' ];
protected $dates    = [ 'deadline_date' ];



/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function getTasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Http\Models\Task',
        'fairkatert_task_assign_milestone'
    );
}



/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCloseTasks()
{
    return $this->getTasks()
        ->where('status', 'close')
        ->count();
}



/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOpenTasks()
{
    return $this->getTasks()
        ->where('status', 'open')
        ->count();
}



/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getMilestoneProgress()
{
    $total  = $this->getTasks()->count();
    $close  = $this->getCloseTasks();

    if($total === 0)
    {
        $result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $result = 100 * $close / $total;
    }

    return number_format($result, 2, '.', '');
}



/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUnorderedTasks()
{
    $task = Task::where([
        'ordered' => false
    ])->get();

    return $task;
}

 }
```

Form

```
<form method="post" >
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" value="{{ milestone.name }}" placeholder="Milestone">
<label>Deadline</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="deadline" value="{{ milestone.deadline_date|date('d.m.Y') }}" placeholder="Datum">
<label>Beschreibung</label>
<textarea id="mytextarea" class="form-control input-sm" name="description" rows="5"  placeholder="Beschreibung">{{ milestone.description }}</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    {% if edit == true %}
        <button type="submit" formaction="{{ url('milestone/' ~ milestone.id ~ '/edit') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success margin-t-5 p">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Milestone bearbeiten
        </button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" formaction="{{ url('milestone/create') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success margin-t-5 p">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Milestone speichern
        </button>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your link https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqNbW.jpg 
If your date format is `d-m-Y` then

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
```

won't work, because you're not specifying the correct format; you need

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);
```

The format that you specify as the date-format for your value must match the actual format of the date string that you want to convert to a Carbon object.